# DNS issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns, ubuntu-16.04

I recently upgraded my virtual machines to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS and couldn't get DNS to work.

> > nsloookup 
> >     ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tried the following but still the issue is there:

https://willhaley.com/blog/resolvconf-dns-issue-after-ubuntu-xenial-upgrade/

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-dns-problems-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-16-10.html

something to add here.

ok something to add here. 
I set up a tcp dump on the my machine with

> > sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 | grep xx.xx.xx.xx.53 (where xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip address of the proxy server)
> >     I don't get a response back as below

`21:29:55.150092 IP yy.yy.yy.yy.37459 > xx.xx.xx.xx..53: 4219+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)
21:30:00.150044 IP yy.yy.yy.yy.37459 > xx.xx.xx.xx..53: 4219+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)
21:30:05.150172 IP yy.yy.yy.yy.37459 > xx.xx.xx.xx..53: 4219+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)`

Firewall rules seems to be fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I get it working now. The main issue was, the latest version of dnsmasq on Ubuntu 16.04 by default only allows responses within the same subnet, in order to allow multiple subnets I need to add

`interface=*`

to my /etc/dnsmasq.d/10-local-dns-server file.
This resolved the issue.